# How to start Gulp server for Yeoman app?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, gulp

1. I'm trying to build my first application using Yeoman + angular
       + gulp.
2. I've also created an application using gulp, which works completely fine.
3. Following is the step I followed to
   install the application,

   1. npm install -g yo
   2. npm install -g generator-angular  (in this I've asked to select between gulp and grunt, so I selected gulp)
   3. install gulp and related plugins mentioned in gulpjs file
   4. try to run an application using gulp

Here is the gulpfile.js

```
    // Generated on 2016-07-28 using generator-angular 0.15.1
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var openURL = require('open');
var lazypipe = require('lazypipe');
var rimraf = require('rimraf');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

var yeoman = {
  app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
  dist: 'dist'
};

var paths = {
  scripts: [yeoman.app + '/scripts/**/*.js'],
  styles: [yeoman.app + '/styles/**/*.css'],
  test: ['test/spec/**/*.js'],
  testRequire: [
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'test/mock/**/*.js',
    'test/spec/**/*.js'
  ],
  karma: 'karma.conf.js',
  views: {
    main: yeoman.app + '/index.html',
    files: [yeoman.app + '/views/**/*.html']
  }
};

////////////////////////
// Reusable pipelines //
////////////////////////

var lintScripts = lazypipe()
  .pipe($.jshint, '.jshintrc')
  .pipe($.jshint.reporter, 'jshint-stylish');

var styles = lazypipe()
  .pipe($.autoprefixer, 'last 1 version')
  .pipe(gulp.dest, '.tmp/styles');

///////////
// Tasks //
///////////

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});


gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.styles)
    .pipe(styles());
});

gulp.task('lint:scripts', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(lintScripts());
});

gulp.task('clean:tmp', function (cb) {
  rimraf('./.tmp', cb);
});

gulp.task('start:client', ['start:server', 'styles'], function () {
  openURL('http://localhost:9000');
});

gulp.task('start:server', function() {
  $.connect.server({
    root: [yeoman.app, '.tmp'],
    livereload: true,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    port: 9000
  });
});

gulp.task('start:server:test', function() {
  $.connect.server({
    root: ['test', yeoman.app, '.tmp'],
    livereload: true,
    port: 9001
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  $.watch(paths.styles)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe(styles())
    .pipe($.connect.reload());

  $.watch(paths.views.files)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.connect.reload());

  $.watch(paths.scripts)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe(lintScripts())
    .pipe($.connect.reload());

  $.watch(paths.test)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe(lintScripts());

  gulp.watch('bower.json', ['bower']);
});

gulp.task('serve', function (cb) {
  runSequence('clean:tmp',
    ['lint:scripts'],
    ['start:client'],
    'watch', cb);
});

gulp.task('serve:prod', function() {
  $.connect.server({
    root: [yeoman.dist],
    livereload: true,
    port: 9000
  });
});

gulp.task('test', ['start:server:test'], function () {
  var testToFiles = paths.testRequire.concat(paths.scripts, paths.test);
  return gulp.src(testToFiles)
    .pipe($.karma({
      configFile: paths.karma,
      action: 'watch'
    }));
});

// inject bower components
gulp.task('bower', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.views.main)
    .pipe(wiredep({
      directory: yeoman.app + '/bower_components',
      ignorePath: '..'
    }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.app + '/views'));
});

///////////
// Build //
///////////

gulp.task('clean:dist', function (cb) {
  rimraf('./dist', cb);
});

gulp.task('client:build', ['html', 'styles'], function () {
  var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');

  return gulp.src(paths.views.main)
    .pipe($.useref({searchPath: [yeoman.app, '.tmp']}))
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe($.minifyCss({cache: true}))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist));
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
  return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/views/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/views'));
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
  return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
        optimizationLevel: 5,
        progressive: true,
        interlaced: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/images'));
});

gulp.task('copy:extras', function () {
  return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/*/.*', { dot: true })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist));
});

gulp.task('copy:fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/fonts/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean:dist'], function () {
  runSequence(['images', 'copy:extras', 'copy:fonts', 'client:build']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

After following above steps on command line, the application terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use '`gulp serve`' command to start the server.

To Build : `gulp build` OR `gulp`

Run karma/jasmine test script : Use '`gulp test`'

Comment: Would you please help me to add "browser-sync" plugin in existing gulpjs file? -> gulpjs has been updated in question. This is just to inform that, I've noticed that 'livereload' is available in gulpjs and also installed livereload plugin, but still it's not working.

Comment: Browsersync will work once install the angularjs-gulp generator. Try to change anything in code and check whether reflect in browser without refresh